# How to get Visual Studio Code to display git origin repository status and sync controls in the "SOURCE CONTROL PROVIDERS" section?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In the SCM pane, there used to be a "SOURCE CONTROL PROVIDERS" section, with  git origin repo status and sync controls. However that section has disappeared.  Instead, I have to use git command-line fetch to determine if I'm ahead or behind the origin, and use pull & push to sync changes.

Is there anyway to get the "SOURCE CONTROL PROVIDERS" section back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround:**

1. Add **any** extra repo's folder into workspace
2. Check SCM pane now has the SOURCE CONTOL PROVIDERS section at the top

**Comment**:

I don't know why, however, when there is only one repo in the workspace, the "SOURCE CONTOL PROVIDERS" section is not displayed.  Adding one or more other repos seems to fix this.